# python, dictionary and int error

Tags: python, dictionary, global

I have a very frustrating python problem. In this code

```
fixedKeyStringInAVar = "SomeKey"

def myFunc(a, b):
    global sleepTime
    global fixedKeyStringInAVar
    varMe=int("15")
    sleepTime[fixedKeyStringInAVar] = varMe*60*1000
    #more code
```

Now this works. BUT sometimes when I run this function I get

```
TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
```

It is extremely annoying since I tried several test cases and could not reproduce the error, yet it happens very often when I run the full code. The code reads data from a db, access sites, etc. so its hard for me to go through the data since it reads from several sources and depends on 3rd party input that changes (websites).

What could this error be?

Comment: Could you add the stack trace on the error, or at least on what line does the error occur?
Also the line breaks in your code got mangled because you did not format it (with four spaces at the beginning of each line).  If you do that it will be easier to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Don't use `global` keyword in a function unless you'd like to change binding of a global name.
2. Search for '`sleepTime =`' in your code. You are binding an int object to the `sleepTime` name at some point in your program.

Comment: yep, i did sleepTime = int at one place. The problem was... while moving code i happen to have the same variable name. I changed it to waitTime and left the global to sleepTime.

Answer (score 1):

Your sleepTime is a global variable. It could be changed to be an int at some point in your program.

The item assignment is the "foo[bar] = baz" construction in your function.